# How to have list() consume __iter__ without calling __len__?

Tags: python

I have a class with both an `__iter__` and a `__len__` methods. The latter uses the former to count all elements.

It works like the following:

```
class A:
    def __iter__(self):
        print("iter")
        for _ in range(5):
            yield "something"

    def __len__(self):
        print("len")
        n = 0
        for _ in self:
            n += 1
        return n
```

Now if we take e.g. the length of an instance it prints `len` and `iter`, as expected:

```
>>> len(A())
len
iter
5
```

But if we call `list()` it calls both `__iter__` and `__len__`:

```
>>> list(A())
len
iter
iter
['something', 'something', 'something', 'something', 'something']
```

It works as expected if we make a generator expression:

```
>>> list(x for x in A())
iter
['something', 'something', 'something', 'something', 'something']
```

I would assume `list(A())` and `list(x for x in A())` to work the same but they don’t.

Note that it appears to first call `__iter__`, then `__len__`, then loop over the iterator:

```
class B:
    def __iter__(self):
        print("iter")

        def gen():
            print("gen")
            yield "something"

        return gen()

    def __len__(self):
        print("len")
        return 1

print(list(B()))
```

Output:

```
iter
len
gen
['something']
```

---

How can I get `list()` not to call `__len__` so that my instance’s iterator is not consumed twice? I could define e.g. a `length` or `size` method and one would then call `A().size()` but that’s less pythonic.

I tried to compute the length in `__iter__` and cache it so that subsequent calls to `__len__` don’t need to iter again but `list()` calls `__len__` without starting to iterate so it doesn’t work.

Note that in my case I work on very large data collections so caching all items is not an option.

Comment: Why does __len__ implementation must call __iter__? Does __iter__ genetare new data each time it's called?

Comment: @Daniel No it’s always the same data but it must iterate over it to get its length; we don’t know it in advance.

Comment: In what stage of A instance do you know? on __init__? on a setter method?

Comment: @Daniel I won’t know until I iterate over the data. Each class instance parses one file; I can’t know how many elements there are in that file without parsing it.

Comment: `__len__` should be only defined for types for which it can be made idempotent. That you have a generator means that perhaps you shouldn't really have `__len__`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: I'm not sure I fully understand your use of the term *idempotent* there. Are you saying that only fixed-length types (like tuples, but not lists) should have `__len__` defined? If not, then you probably mean something else. Personally, I would say you're welcome to define `__len__` as long as you can make it *efficient*.

Comment: @Daniel: I saw you deleted your answer. For what it's worth, I think you were on the right track, especially considering the questions you've asked in these comments. The issue is: how to make `__len__` *fast*, and if you have some internal counter that is incremented every time you add an element and decremented every time you remove an element, then `__len__` can simply return the value of that counter. Obviously, it's even simpler if you can't add or remove elements.

Comment: This is easy - just detect the caller of object with type `A` using `inspect` module. If caller is `list`, then temporarily rename `__len__` to something else so that it is not detected. This is like hide and seek game :)

Comment: @denfromufa That’s a terribly ugly solution :)

Comment: @bfontaine relative to the backwards data structure that you are trying to implement this look like a perfect and only solution right now

Comment: @denfromufa No the only solution is the accepted answer: Don’t define `__len__`.

Comment: your question states that you still need len()

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a safe bet that the `list()` constructor is detecting that `len()` is available and calling it in order to pre-allocate storage for the list.

Your implementation is pretty much completely backwards. You are implementing `__len__()` by using `__iter__()`, which is not what Python expects. The expectation is that `len()` is a fast, efficient way to determine the length *in advance*.

I don't think you can convince `list(A())` not to call `len`. As you have already observed, you can create an intermediate step that prevents `len` from being called.

You should definitely cache the result, if the sequence is immutable. If there are as many items as you speculate, there's no sense computing `len` more than once.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense.

Comment: Anecdote: I once implemented `__len__` as `return len(list(iter(self)))`, and discovered this was a Very Bad Idea when my test coverage tracking stopped working.  Turns out, `list(foo)` calls `__len__` which calls `list()`, which calls `__len__` etc. until there's a MaximumRecursionError -- which shuts down coverage tracking -- and then `list()` suppresses that error and assumes `__len__` is not available.  Slow and with unexpected side effects!

Comment: Just call `sys.setrecursionlimit()` with a low number to make it go faster. :-) :-) :-)

Answer (score -2):

You don't have to implement `__len__`. For an class that is iterable, it just needs to implement **either** of below:

- `__iter__`, which returns an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types), or a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) as in your class A & B
- `__getitems__`, as long as it raises `IndexError` when the index is out of range

Blow code still works:

```
class A:
    def __iter__(self):
        print("iter")
        for _ in range(5):
            yield "something"

print list(A())
```

Which outputs:

```
iter
['something', 'something', 'something', 'something', 'something']
```

Comment: I don’t *have to* but I want to be able to get the size of my data, and defining `__len__` allows me to use `len(A())` instead of e.g. `len(list(A()))`. (ETA: also `list(A())` won’t work if I my instances yields millions of large objects, I need to write some code to consume the iterator and increment a counter for that. `__len__` seemed like a good place to do that)

Comment: @bfontaine, then I'm a little confused with your requirement. do you just want to get size of the data, or also iterator/consume the data (at some point)?

Comment: Both. Iterating over the data is the main requirement, but being able to get its size directly would be a great addition that’ll save a few keystrokes when I play with the data in the REPL.

Comment: ok, I don't see a way to avoid calling `__len__` in `list(A())` (when you have that method implementation).