# Why does list ask about __len__?

Tags: python, list, python-internals

```
class Foo:
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        print('getitem', item)
        if item == 6:
            raise IndexError
        return item**2
    def __len__(self):
        print('len')
        return 3

class Bar:
    def __iter__(self):
        print('iter')
        return iter([3, 5, 42, 69])
    def __len__(self):
        print('len')
        return 3
```

Demo:

```
>>> list(Foo())
len
getitem 0
getitem 1
getitem 2
getitem 3
getitem 4
getitem 5
getitem 6
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
>>> list(Bar())
iter
len
[3, 5, 42, 69]
```

Why does `list` call `__len__`?  It doesn't seem to use the result for anything obvious.  A `for` loop doesn't do it.  This isn't mentioned anywhere in the [iterator protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types), which just talks about `__iter__` and `__next__`.

Is this Python reserving space for the list in advance, or something clever like that?

(CPython 3.6.0 on Linux)

Comment: In my testing on 3.8, it asks *twice*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel [fixed](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/31816)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

See the [Rationale section from PEP 424](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0424/#rationale) that introduced `__length_hint__` and offers insight on the motivation:

> Being able to pre-allocate lists based on the expected size, as estimated by `__length_hint__` , can be a significant optimization. *CPython has been observed to run some code faster than PyPy, purely because of this optimization being present.*

In addition to that, the documentation [for `object.__length_hint__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__length_hint__) verifies the fact that this is purely an optimization feature:

> Called to implement `operator.length_hint()`. Should return an estimated length for the object (which may be greater or less than the actual length). The length must be an integer `>= 0`. *This method is **purely an optimization** and is never required for correctness*.

So `__length_hint__` is here because it can result in some nice optimizations.

`PyObject_LengthHint`, [first tries to get a value from `object.__len__`  (if it is defined)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/abstract.c#L88) and then tries to see if `object.__length_hint__` is available. If neither is there, it returns a default value of `8` for lists.

`listextend`, which is called from `list_init` as Eli stated in his answer, was modified according to this PEP to offer this optimization for anything that defines either a `__len__` or a `__length_hint__`.

`list` isn't the only one that benefits from this, of course, [`bytes` objects do](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0217f632ee40ec3dab11e6f88e82b6ed24974861/Objects/bytesobject.c#L2688):

```
>>> bytes(Foo())
len
getitem 0
...
b'\x00\x01\x04\t\x10\x19'
```

so [do `bytearray` objects but, only when you `extend` them](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0217f632ee40ec3dab11e6f88e82b6ed24974861/Objects/bytearrayobject.c#L1616):

```
>>> bytearray().extend(Foo())
len
getitem 0
...
```

and `tuple` objects which create [an intermediary sequence to](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0bdd9e516e8cb7f4a7d8198bf36194c8328c0f2c/Objects/abstract.c#L1794) populate themselves:

```
>>> tuple(Foo())
len
getitem 0
...
(0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25)
```

---

If anybody is wandering why exactly `'iter'` is printed *before* `'len'` in class `Bar` and not after as happens with class `Foo`:

This is because if the object in hand defines an `__iter__` [Python *will first call it* to get the iterator](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0bdd9e516e8cb7f4a7d8198bf36194c8328c0f2c/Objects/abstract.c#L3118), thereby running the `print('iter')` too. The same doesn't happen if it falls back to using `__getitem__`.

Answer (score 32):

`list` is a list object constructor that will allocate an initial slice of memory for its contents.  The list constructor attempts to figure out a good size for that initial slice of memory by checking the length hint or the length of any object passed into the constructor .  See the call to [`PyObject_LengthHint`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0bdd9e516e8cb7f4a7d8198bf36194c8328c0f2c/Objects/abstract.c#L82) in the Python [source here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L833). This place is called from the list constructor -- [list_init](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/06d0b8b67e8aebd8fe4c34e97d6915c11f4afa30/Objects/listobject.c#L2685)

If your object has no `__len__` or `__length_hint__`, that's OK -- a [default value of 8](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0bdd9e516e8cb7f4a7d8198bf36194c8328c0f2c/Objects/abstract.c#L82) is used; it just may be less efficient due to reallocations.

Comment: Is that a CPython implementation detail, or a documented part of Python language?  Because it can cause an infinite recursion if you don't know about that call in advance.

Comment: "*it needs a size*" and "*a default value is used*" seem to contradict each other. Instead of "it needs a size" how about "it uses the size to preallocate memory."

Comment: @Robᵩ: I meant to say it needs some size to get started. Not that it needs `__len__`, just some size. The size can be either from `__len__` or from a default. Feel free to propose and edit and let editors decide what the clearer phrasing is - I don't feel strongly about it

Comment: Note that the optimization of knowing the `len` in advance could turn out to be a disadvantage if you lie (see OP) about the length. :-)

Comment: @wim: not 100% sure but I think this is a CPython implementation detail, which also makes it a de-facto part of the Python language since there's no official implementation-agnostic spec. See additional discussion in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189968/how-to-have-list-consume-iter-without-calling-len -- I don't think a correctly/reasonably implemented `__len__` should cause issues

Comment: Probably I've found the code - https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L2708

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: I prepared the answer for [[SO]: Why __len__ is called and the result is not used when iterating with __getitem__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57887023/why-len-is-called-and-the-result-is-not-used-when-iterating-with-getitem), which was marked as a dupe (as it's exactly this question) while I was writing it, so it was no longer possible to post it there, and since I already had it, I decided to post it here (with small adjustments).

Here's a modified version of your code that makes things a bit clearer.

*code00.py*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys


class Foo:
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        print("{0:s}.{1:s}: {2:d}".format(self.__class__.__name__, "getitem", item))
        if item == 6:
            raise IndexError
        return item ** 2


class Bar:
    def __iter__(self):
        print("{0:s}.{1:s}".format(self.__class__.__name__, "iter"))
        return iter([3, 5, 42, 69])

    def __len__(self):
        result = 3
        print("{0:s}.{1:s}: {2:d}".format(self.__class__.__name__, "len", result))
        return result


def main():
    print("Start ...\n")
    for class_obj in [Foo, Bar]:
        inst_obj = class_obj()
        print("Created {0:s} instance".format(class_obj.__name__))
        list_obj = list(inst_obj)
        print("Converted instance to list")
        print("{0:s}: {1:}\n".format(class_obj.__name__, list_obj))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main()
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q041474829]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> Start ...
>
> Created Foo instance
> Foo.getitem: 0
> Foo.getitem: 1
> Foo.getitem: 2
> Foo.getitem: 3
> Foo.getitem: 4
> Foo.getitem: 5
> Foo.getitem: 6
> Converted instance to list
> Foo: [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
>
> Created Bar instance
> Bar.iter
> Bar.len: 3
> Converted instance to list
> Bar: [3, 5, 42, 69]
>
>
> Done.
> ```

As seen, *__len__* is called when the list is constructed. Browsing [[GitHub]: python/cpython - (master) cpython/Objects/listobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c):

- *list___init__* (which is the initializer: ***__init__*** (*tp_init* member in *PyList_Type*)) calls *list___init___impl*
- *list___init___impl* calls *list_extend*
- *list_extend* calls *PyObject_LengthHint* (`n = PyObject_LengthHint(iterable, 8);`)
- *PyObject_LengthHint* (in *abstract.c*), does the check:

  ```c
  Py_ssize_t
  PyObject_LengthHint(PyObject *o, Py_ssize_t defaultvalue)

      // ...

      if (_PyObject_HasLen(o)) {
          res = PyObject_Length(o);

      // ...
  ```

So, it's an optimization feature that works for iterables that define *__len__*.

This is particularly handy when the iterable has a large number of elements, so that they are allocated at once, and therefore skip the list growth mechanism (didn't check if still applies, but at one point, it was): "***Space increases by ~12.5% when full***" (according to David M. Beazley). It is very useful when lists were constructed out of (other) lists or tuples. 
For example, constructing a list from an iterable (that doesn't define *__len__*) with ***1000*** elements, instead of allocating everything at once, there will be ***~41*** (**`log1.125(1000 / 8)`**) operations (allocation, data shifting, deallocation) required only for increasing the new list as it gets filled (with elements from the source iterable).

Needless to say that for "modern" iterables, the improvement no longer applies.