# Why does calling list() on an instance with an __iter__() method cause recursion?

Tags: python

I'm working in Python 3.7 and I've got something like this:

```py
class Foo:
    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self.some_sequence

    def __len__(self):
        return len(list(self))


>>> len(Foo())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __len__
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __len__
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __len__
  [Previous line repeated 496 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I'm sure I'm missing some obvious reason as to why this always causes a recursion error, but I can't think of why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `len` method call `__len__` method of an object to calculate the length. In your case, in the `__len__` method, you are again calling `len` of `list of self`, `list` actually ends up calling `__len__` and this leads to recursion.

The below code causes the recursion:

```
def __len__(self):
    return len(list(self))
```

Your call is stack is like below:

```
len(Foo()) --> __len__(self) --> len(list(self)) -->list(self)--> __len__(self)--> len(list(self)) --> list(self) --> __len__(self)-->so on
```

It is unclear to me as to why you would call `len(list(self))`. You should actually be getting the length of the data which you store in the object of this class and return it rather than calling `len(list(self))`

The `list` function actually calls the `__len__` function of the object which actually results in the recursion. Please refer to the related Q on SO: [Why does list ask about __len__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474829/why-does-list-ask-about-len)

Comment: OP is calling len on a *list*, not on self. Is this actually causing the problem?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds, Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474829/why-does-list-ask-about-len

Comment: I see, well then it's because `list(self)` is calling `__len__`, not the user calling `len()`.

Comment: @Jay: The information in your link is correct, but it's not the explanation your answer gives.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds, Thanks for your comment, I have updated the answer. Please check now.

Comment: @user2357112, I have updated the answer. Please check now. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 8):

To compute the `len` of your object, you call `list` on your object.

To figure out how much space to reserve, `list` calls `len` on your object. ([It uses](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.2/Objects/listobject.c#L873) `PyObject_LengthHint`, which tries `len` and `__length_hint__`.)

To compute the `len` of your object...

There's the infinite recursion.

(Also that'd be a really inefficient `__len__` implementation even if it worked - `__len__` is generally expected to be constant-time.)

Answer (score -1):

You would get the same error even if you didn't use `list` like the following

```
def __len__(self):
    return len((self))
```

And you are indeed doing a recursion here with no terminal condition. It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish here.