# Why __len__ is called and the result is not used when iterating with __getitem__?

Tags: python, iteration

Consider the following example:

```
import random


class Class1:
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        print('getitem', item)
        result = random.randint(0, 10)
        if not result:
            raise IndexError
        return result


class Class2(Class1):
    def __len__(self):
        print('len', 3)
        return 3


print(list(Class1()))
print(list(Class2()))
```

Output:

```
getitem 0
getitem 1
[10]
len 3
getitem 0
getitem 1
getitem 2
getitem 3
getitem 4
[8, 10, 2, 10]
```

So, when iterating through `Class1()` there is no `__len__` but the code works correctly. When there is `__len__` in `Class2()` it is called but the result `3` is not used at all, the iteration continues after getting 3 items. My question is: why `__len__` is called? There is no reason to call it if the result is ignored.

Comment: Guess: `__len__` is part of [the definition of a *sequence type*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence), so it's just called as a check whether it duck-types as such…?

Comment: @deceze I'm not sure. If you change `Class1` to subclass `int` (which has no `__len__`) then `list(Class1())` still works, so `list(...)` does not care if the call to `__len__` because it does not exists (but it does care if it raises an exception)

Comment: I believe it's only used to pre-assign a destination list of an appropriate size, as an optimisation; if you iterate over a `Class2` instance in other contexts (e.g. a `for` loop) `__len__` doesn't get called.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think you are correct. If `Class2.__len__` is changed to return a negative number then `list(Class2())` fails `ValueError: __len__() should return >= 0`

Comment: @DeepSpace that's a general requirement for `__len__`; [*"an integer `>=` 0"*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some indications in [PEP 424: A method for exposing a length hint](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0424/):

> CPython currently defines a **length_hint** method on several types,
>   such as various iterators. This method is then used by various other
>   functions (such as list) to presize lists based on the estimate
>   returned by **length_hint**. Types which are not sized, and thus
>   should not define **len**, can then define **length_hint**, to allow
>   estimating or computing a size (such as many iterators).
>
> And:
>
> Being able to pre-allocate lists based on the expected size, as
>   estimated by **length_hint**, can be a significant optimization.
>   CPython has been observed to run some code faster than PyPy, purely
>   because of this optimization being present.

So it seems that `list` calls `__len__` in order to pre-allocate the list. Your list can grow as large as it wants after that.