# python list constructor for custom type - length called twice

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following python code:

```py
class View:
    pass


v = View()
print(list(v))
```

When run, this gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 35, in <module>
    print(list(v))
TypeError: 'View' object is not iterable
```

Makes sense. Let's add the `__iter__` to `View`

```py
class View:
    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(5):
            yield i
```

This works now, and correctly produces `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

However, consider what happens if `View` has `__len__` method defined:

```py
class View:
    def __len__(self):
        print("len called")
        return 2

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(5):
            yield i

v = View()
print(list(v))
```

When run, this produces:

```
len called
len called
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Not only `__len__` is called twice, it seems it is also not "respected" (I am returning 2 as length, but my `__iter__` produces 5 values, and the list correctly composes of 5 values)

What is going on? (Note that this is not an idle curiosity. In my application, I have an expensive `__len__` method and calling it twice is slowing down my initialization time)

Comment: The call to length is only to determine how much space to allocate, it's not binding (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/41474829/3001761). Not sure why it's called twice, those examples suggest it used to be called once.

Comment: Ah. Thanks @jonrsharpe I should mention that I am using python 3.8.6 for this.

Comment: I tried some similar code and it was only called once. Interesting though.

Comment: It's maybe a bug, see https://bugs.python.org/issue39829

Comment: In terms of improving performance, could you have a faster (but presumably less accurate) implementation of [`__length_hint__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__length_hint__)? CPython will use that for the list size allocation if available.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's a good idea. I will do that. Do you want to write a short answer to this question with the link to above python issue? I will approve that answer.

Comment: Actually you can't use `__length_hint__`, that's only called if `__len__` *isn't* defined: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ace3f9a0ce7b9fe8ae757fdd614f1e7a171f92b0/Objects/abstract.c#L79-L148

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [Why does list ask about __len__?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41474829/3001761) the `__len__` method is called to get an approximation of how much space needs to be allocated to the list. Note it's just an *approximation*, whether you're iterating using `__iter__` or `__getitem__` that length is not binding:

```
>>> class GetItemIter:
...     def __len__(self):
...             return 2
...     def __getitem__(self, index):
...             return [0, 1, 2][index]
...
>>> list(GetItemIter())
[0, 1, 2]
>>> class IterIter:
...     def __len__(self):
...             return 2
...     def __iter__(self):
...             return iter([0, 1, 2])
...
>>> list(IterIter())
[0, 1, 2]
```

From Python 3.8 the list constructor is [checking the length *twice*](https://bugs.python.org/issue39829). This is in the bug tracker, but may be considered an implementation detail:

> The number of times we can `__len__` on the constructor is an
> implementation detail. The reason is called now twice is because there
> is an extra check for the preallocation logic...